# changing button text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, button, text

How do I change the text of the button into the result of my array ?

here is my code:

```
var lastLength = bestRes.length;
for( var x = 0; x< lastLength; x++){

    var specMatchTime = new Date(Date.parse(bestRes[x]["match_time"]));
    var specMatchHour = specMatchTime.getHours();
    var specMatchMinutes = specMatchTime.getMinutes();

    var rowDiv = document.createElement("div");
    rowDiv.className += "row";

    var colDiv = document.createElement("div");
    colDiv.className += "col-md-2 matchDetails";
    colDiv.innerHTML = ''+specMatchHour + ":" + specMatchMinutes;
    rowDiv.appendChild(colDiv);

    colDiv = document.createElement("div");
    colDiv.className += "col-md-2 matchDetails";
    colDiv.innerHTML = bestRes[x]['league'];
    rowDiv.appendChild(colDiv);

    colDiv = document.createElement("div");
    colDiv.className += "col-md-4 matchDetails";
    colDiv.innerHTML = bestRes[x]['home']+' vs '+ bestRes[x]['away'];
    rowDiv.appendChild(colDiv);

    colDiv = document.createElement("div");
    colDiv.className += "col-md-1 matchButton";
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.className += "btn";
    var moneyHome = bestRes[x]['money_home'];
    moneyHome.toString();
    button.innerHTML = moneyHome;
    colDiv.innerHTML = '<input id="buttonID" type="button" class="btn"/>';
    rowDiv.appendChild(colDiv);
}
```

The button still show blank after that. What is the problem there?

Comment: show some code. the question now is completely unclear.

Comment: Why at the end didn't you append the button to the colDiv by appendChild method?

Answer (score -1):

In general terms you should first find the button element in the DOM tree, then assign the new value with `innerHTML` property, e.g.:

```
var button = document.getElementById('your-button-id');
button.innerHTML = bestRes[x]['home'];
```

In your example try to change the last part in this manner:

```
var button = document.createElement("input");
button.type = "button";
button.id = "buttonID";
button.className = "btn";
button.value = finalRes[x]['money_home'];
colDiv.appendChild(button);
rowDiv.appendChild(colDiv);
```

Comment: i tried but it gives me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null =\

Comment: i found it ady, just change button.innerHTML to button.value will do. thanks anyways!

Comment: Do not set `innerHTML` like this. If new text contains HTML characters they may be interpreted as HTML code. Also, for `<input>` the text is changed by `button.value`. Downvote for not verifying your answer.